# firestore: user can create but can't overwrite existing belonging to another user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

so looking at my firestore rules i'm thinking there is a potential for a user to overtake another user's document.

I have a write rule that looks like

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner_uid
            || request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner_uid;
```

the issue here i'm thinking is that if a user updates an existing document they do not own by passing in their `uid` in the `owner_uid` field, they will effectively take over ownership of the document.

How can i craft the write rule better so that

```
request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner_uid;
```

only applies on document creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) in the documentation:

> In some situations, it's useful to break down read and write into more
>   granular operations. For example, your app may want to enforce
>   different conditions on document creation than on document deletion.
>   Or you may want to allow single document reads but deny large queries.
>
> A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a write rule can be
>   broken into create, update, and delete.

So, you can say things like this in your rules:

```
allow create: if <condition>;
```

that will apply only to document creation.